# Sine and cosine expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the greatest possible value of $5\cos x + 6\sin x$.

I attempted to solve this using graphing, however, the answer appears to be an ugly irrational. Is there a better method of solving this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: That's because the answer _is_ an irrational number...

Answer (score 14):

A simple vector-based approach: you recognize in the expression the dot product $$(5, 6) \cdot (\cos x, \sin x).$$ This product is maximized when the two vectors are parallel and it is then the product of the moduli $$\sqrt{5^2+6^2} \cdot 1.$$

Comment: This is nice too.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Let $\theta$ be an angle whose sine is $\frac{5}{\sqrt{61}}$ and whose cosine is $\frac{6}{\sqrt{61}}$. Then our expression is equal to 
$$\sqrt{61}\sin(x+\theta).$$

Answer (score 5):

There is an ad-hoc solution as shown in other answers.

Anyway, the standard approach is to find the roots of the derivative, $-5\sin x+6\cos x=0$, i.e. $\tan x=\frac{6}{5}$, so that $x=\arctan\frac{6}{5}$ or $\pi+\arctan\frac{6}{5}$.

Plug these values in the objective function.

Comment: I'm sorry, my solution is not "ad hoc" - I put it as I did to indicate how to do this more generally. One doesn't need calculus to sort out basic trigonometric identities. Sometimes you want to go for $\sin (x-a)$ or $\cos (x \pm a)$. I think you overstate the case for "the standard approach" in elementary work.

Comment: @Mark: don't take "ad-hoc" as pejorative.

Comment: No, I don't really. But Inwas trying to indicate a systematic approach (!)

Comment: Would your approach apply to $5 \log \sin x+ 6x^3$ ?

Comment: No, but trigonometric problems like this occur often in physics and more generally (I did these trigonometric identities at school). I like your solution a lot.

Comment: I should rephrase "There are pure trigonometric solutions as shown in other answers".

Comment: Have a look at the vector-based approach. Pretty compact... :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)(5^2+6^2)\ge (5\cos x + 6\sin x)^2$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $r^2=5^2+6^2=25+36=61$ and $\alpha = \arctan \frac 56$

You will find that $$5\cos x+6\sin x=r(\sin\alpha\cos x+\cos\alpha \sin x)=r \sin (x+\alpha)$$

Comment: See also [Linear combinations of sine and cosine](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/729974/35416) for more details.

Comment: @MvG Great link